# Can't include files after moving from CPanel to Plesk

Tags: php, cpanel, plesk

I have a base set of files that are included from lots of other files. This saves me having to update lots of files when I made changes. The issues is, in CPanel my directory structure was:

Base: `domain/public_html/base_data`
Subdomain: `domain/public_html/subdomain`

This meant I could just go back one directory and include the file. Now that I have moved to Plesk it is like this:

Base: `domain/httpdocs/base_data`
Subdomain: `domain/subdomains/subdomain/httpdocs/`

The problem with this is none of my includes work when I `../../` out of my current sub domain into the base_data one.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: Just turned error reporting on and got this `open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/base_data/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/rip/httpdocs:/tmp) in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/subdomains/rip/httpdocs/index.php on line 14`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes use ABSOLUTE path.

you can make a `$yourLibPath  =  'domain/httpdocs/base_data/';`

And then include all your libs using this var:

```
include($yourLibPath.'time.lib.php');
```

Comment: I am doing this `require("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/base_data/index.php")` and it doesn't work. When I go to that file, I have put a `echo getcwd()` line in there and can confirm the path is correct. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: what is the error? Also you said you were using `../../` and I dont' see them now. Please dont' change your question on teh fly because it's get harder for us to follow

Comment: There is no error, the contents just don't get included. I changed my code in line with your suggestion of using the absolute path ..... Not changing my question. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah just turned error reporting on. Open base dir restriction in effect. Looking into this now.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this out by overriding the open_basedir path in a vhost.conf file.